# Unable to start program: Access denied

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015

I have reasently uppgraded my computer with a SSD drive. I did a fresh installation of windows. In the process I also uppgraded from win 8.1 to win 10.

I use a decentralized arichive keeping the system on the C:\ drive and documents on a bigger storage drive D:\ .

---

**Problem:** When the win10 installation was finished and so the installation of Visual Studio I went on to open one of my programming projects just to get the following error message when compiling.

```
Microsoft Visual Studio

    Unable to start program
    'D:\...\project\Debug\project.exe'.

    Access denied.
```

- The project hasn't been moved since I use the same storage drive as before the installation.
- When I plugg in the old system containing win 8.1 there are no problems to be found.
- A similar error message pops up if the *.exe file is started from the explorer.

What can be done about this?

*Using Visual Studio 2015 on a Windows 10 computer, programming in C++.*

### Updates

- This also affects new projects & solutions made from Visual Studio 2015
- The location of the *.exe file doesn't seem to matter. Even a new project started on the C:\ drive encounters the same problem.
- Starting the project in a folder with default security acess (windows user ID) gives the same result.

Comment: Sounds like the file is owned by a user ID that exists on Windows 8.1 but not on Windows 10.  You may need to "take ownership" of the files.

Comment: Thanks for commenting @Mr.Llama :)

After some testing, ownership rights has been altered both ways now. Both from win10 granting me rights and from win8.1 granting right to anyone. Rebots have been preformed.

This didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: `Access denied` could also refer to one of the DLLs that `project.exe` references. If you copy some other .exe to the same directory, can you run it (a) from Explorer, (b) from VS 2015?

Comment: Thanks for commenting @dxiv :) I made a try and found something interresting. a) the probram didn't run from either the explorer or VS15. b) The problem I have described seem to apply to any location of the *.exe files. c) If a new project is started and placed on the desktop it won't run either due to the same problem. This seems to be an overall problem.

Comment: Do try to write in some folder which actualy has full control permissions (by default, they DON'T on Vista and later) for the Users group

Comment: Thanks for commenting @PaulStelian :) Doing this seems to lead to the same problem. dxiv might be up to something when mentioning reference problem. But in that case it's a computer global problem and not bound to the directory it self. To bad I don't really know what to make out of that :/

Comment: It's weird, but I've seen antivirus programs sometimes mess up with my executables written with CodeBlocks IDE. It's possible they cause this. I've had such trouble with AVG.

Comment: That's it haha, it was my virus program. I first deactivated it and everything worked, then I activated it again with the setting "Active protection --> Scan *.exe files when executed" off. You have been very helpful @PaulStelian. None of the error messages given have even come close to sugessting the Virus program. (Not that strange tough)

Comment: In my case I considered it true due to a warning from the AV program (AVG in particular) that appeared 2-3 minutes after the access being denied.

Comment: In this case no warning came from the virus program (Avast), my guess is that the scanning process just blocked tha file making windows think it couldn't be acessed. Your comment helped me realise that the Virus progam could have something to do with it tough, so thanks @Paul :)

Comment: No problem. And about solving stuff in comments, I prefer commenting if it's just a hint and answering only when it's close enough to being certain. Just like on another QA site I use, Quora.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution:** Deactivate your Anti-Virus program's active file protection that scans *.exe files when executed.

**Troubleshooting:** The error message *"Acess Denied"* is an indication that the system doesn't reach the program. From this point one should start examine possible obstacles. *Start with deactivating the virus program.* **If** that helps try and find out what part of the virus program that is the problem and deactivate only that part. **Else** continue examine other possible obstacles.